# Prove that $(3+5\sqrt{2})^m=(5+3 \sqrt{2})^n$ has no positive integer solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is my proof ok? I set $b=3+5 \sqrt{2}$, so that we have $b^m=(b+2-3 \sqrt{2})^n$  , or $b^m=(b+\sqrt2(\sqrt2- 3))^n$. Since $RHS<LHS$, $n>m$ .  However, from what we know about binomial expansion, we will have a $b^n$ on the $RHS$ which will not cancel out with anything since it is the highest power, so we will never be able to reduce the $RHS$ to just $b^m$ . I don't really like my proof, is there a better one? And does this have a solution for rational powers, and how can you prove that it does/doesn't? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there is a solution, there is one where the $\sqrt{2}$are replaced by $-\sqrt{2}$. Multiply. 
We get 
$$(3+5\sqrt{2})^m(3-5\sqrt{2})^m=(5+3\sqrt{2})^n(5-3\sqrt{2})^n.$$
That gives $(-41)^m=7^n$, impossible unless $m=n=0$.

Can't have non-zero rationals either. Just raise to the appropriate integer power and use basically the same argument.

Comment: Thanks I understood the multiplication, but how do you know that you can replace the $\sqrt2$ with a -$\sqrt2$?

Comment: There is a fancier way of seeing it. But imagine expanding either one using Binomial Theorem. There will be on each side an integer part and a $\sqrt{2}$ part. They must match, since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. So if on each side you replace the $\sqrt{2}$ part by changing sign, the sides are still equal, but you have the expansions of the conjugates.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't actually know the binomial theorem (haha I know I used it in my proof but I just know the first part) but I can understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your statement about not cancelling.

Hint: consider the function $f(a + b \sqrt{2}) = (a + b \sqrt{2})(a - b \sqrt{2}) = a^2 - 2 b^2$, and note that $f(xy) = f(x) f(y)$.

Comment: My statement about not canceling is saying that if we take the RHS to the power $n$, we will necessarily have a $b^n$ on the RHS and we don't have a $b^n$ present on the LHS, so the RHS can never equal the RHS.

Comment: But other terms might cancel the $b^n$.

Comment: But $b^n$ would be the highest power of $b$, so there is only one term with $b^n$

Comment: For example, $(1+2 \sqrt{2})^m = (9+4 \sqrt{2})^n$ does have solutions (namely $m=2n$).  How does your argument fail in that case?

Comment: You're right, I looked at this as if $b$ is a variable, and there is no other $b^n$ which could cancel it, but $b$ is actually a constant and it can be canceled out by the other constants. Thanks.